# CUDA: Thread synchronization in the same block

Tags: cuda, thread-synchronization

Im trying write program in CUDA but I have problem with synchronization in the same block between threads.

Here is model situation:

```
 10 __global__ void gpu_test_sync()
 11 {
 12     __shared__ int t;
 13     int tid = threadIdx.x;
 14
 15     t = 0;
 16     __threadfence();
 17     __syncthreads();
 18
 19     // for(int i=0; i<1000000 && t<tid; i++); // with fuse
 20     while(t<tid);
 21
 22     t++;
 23     __threadfence();
 24 }
 25
 26 void f_cpu()
 27 {
 28     printf("TEST ... ");
 29     int blocks = 1;
 30     int threads = 2;
 31     gpu_test_sync<<< blocks , threads >>>();
 32     printf("OK\n");
 33 }
```

If threads = 1, everything is ok. If threads > 1, infinite cycling.

Why? Function __threadfence(); should make visible value of t variable for other threads.

How I can solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe your kernel will be able to do what you are trying to do because of the divergent branch in `while(t<tid)` causing all threads of the warp to loop indefinitely and never arriving at the line `++t`.

## Long explanation

scroll to 'The important part' for the important stuff if you already know about threads and blocks and warps:

(I have no experience with the Kepler architecture, yet. Some of these numbers may be different if not using Fermi.)

Some terms need to be explained to understand the next section:
The following terms relate to the logical (logical as in software constructs) threads:

- thread – a single thread of execution.
- block – a group of multiple threads that execute the same kernel.
- grid – a group of blocks.

The following terms relate to the physical (physical as in hardware architecture dependent) threads:

- core – a single compute core, one core runs exactly one instruction at a time.
- warp – a group of threads that execute in parallel on the hardware, a warp consists of 32 threads on current generation CUDA hardware.

Kernels are executed by one or more Streaming Multiprocessors (SM). A typical
mid-to-high-end GeForce card from the Fermi family (GeForce 400 and GeForce
500 series) has 8-16 SMs on a single GPU[[Fermi whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf)]. Each SM consists of 32 CUDA Cores (cores). Threads are scheduled for execution by the warp schedulers, each SM has
two warp scheduler units that work in a lockstep fashion. The smallest unit that
a warp scheduler can schedule is called a warp, which consists of 32 threads on all
CUDA hardware released so far at the time of writing. Only one warp may execute
at a time on each SM.

Threads in CUDA are much more lightweight than CPU threads, context switches
are cheaper and all threads of a warp execute the same instruction or have to
wait while the other threads in the warp execute the instruction, this is called Sin-
gle Instruction Multiple Thread (SIMT) and is similar to traditional CPU Single
Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) instructions such as SSE, AVX, NEON, Al-
tivec etc., this has consequences when using conditional statements as described
further down.

To allow for problems which demand more than 32 threads to solve the CUDA
threads are arranged into logical groups called *blocks* and *grids* of sizes that are
defined by the software developer. A block is a 3-dimensional collection of threads,
each thread in the block has its own individual 3-dimensional identification num-
ber to allow the developer to distinguish between the threads in the kernel code.
Threads within a single block can share data through shared memory, this reduces
the load on global memory. Shared memory has a much lower latency than global
memory but is a limited resource, the user can choose between (per block) 16 kB
shared memory and 48 kB L1 cache or 48 kB shared memory and 16 kB L1 cache.

Several blocks of threads in turn can be grouped into a grid. Grids are 3-dimensional
arrays of blocks. The maximum block size is tied to the available hardware resources while the grids can be of (almost) arbitrary size. Blocks within a grid can
only share data through global memory, which is the on-GPU memory which has
the highest latency.

A Fermi GPU can have 48 warps (1536 threads) active at once per SM, given
that the threads use little enough local and shared memory to fit all at the same
time. Context switches between threads are fast since registers are allocated to the
threads and hence there is no need for saving and restoring registers and shared
memory between thread switches. The result is that it is actually desired to over-
allocate the hardware since it will hide memory stalls inside the kernels by letting
the warp schedulers switch the currently active warp whenever a stall occurs.

### The important part

The thread warp is a hardware group of threads that execute on the same *Streaming Multiprocessor* (SM).
Threads of a warp can be compared to sharing a common program counter between
the threads, hence all threads must execute the same line of program code. If the
code has some brancing statements such as `if ... then ... else` the warp must
first execute the threads that enter the first block, while the other threads of the
warp wait, next the threads that enter the next block will execute while the other
threads wait and so on. Because of this behaviour conditional statements should
be avoided in GPU code if possible. When threads of a warp follow different lines
of execution it is known as having divergent threads. While conditional blocks
should be kept to a minimum inside CUDA kernels, it is sometimes possible to
reorder statements so that all threads of the same warp follow only a single path
of execution in an `if ... then ... else` block and mitigate this limitation.

The `while` and `for` statements are branching statements, so it is not limited to `if`.

Comment: I thought that threads are independment in the block.

Function __syncthreads(); is for synchronization between threads from diferent blocks?

Comment: Every thread in a warp tries to execute the code in lockstep - the entire purpose of cuda is to do roughly the same thing lots and lots of times all at the same time.

Comment: All threads of a warp execute the same instruction, or wait, they can not execute different parts of a kernel in parallel

Comment: Ok. What is different between block and warp? For example if I call gpu_f<<<1,64>>> then block have two warps(32 threads)? Or?

Comment: Yes, `gpu_f<<<1,64>>>` should execute using two warps. A block is a logical grouping of threads, the warp is the low level hardware grouping that comes from design choices when implementing the GPU in silicon. I've updated my answer to give an introduction to blocks, warps and threads.

Comment: Great answer but unrelated to his actual problem. The real problem is that the code contains an infinite loop because of the semicolon after `while(t<tid)` which keeps the increment out of the loop.

Comment: @JoakimNohlgård "Threads of a warp can be compared to sharing a common program counter between the threads, hence all threads must execute the same line of program code." Really? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473593/gpgpu-consequence-of-having-a-common-pc-in-a-warp#comment62050641_25473593

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop when you launch the kernel with more than one thread because `while(t<tid);` is an infinite loop for any threads with an `idx` greater than zero.

At this point your problem is not related with synchronization of threads but with the loop you have implemented.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is get a series of threads to execute in serial, then you are abusing CUDA.

It is also not going to work, because any threads past the first will never receive an updated t - you have to call __syncthreads() for shared variables to refresh, but you can only do that if all of the threads are executing the same thing - i.e. not waiting.